# What are some 64-bit consistent hashing algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I was looking at Murmurhash but the hashed value is only 32 bit.  Does anyone know of any 64-bit consistent hashing algorithms?

Comment: Not according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash.

Comment: skein, used in the xkcd hash cracking competition

Comment: Use 128-bit Murmurhash and discard the high 64 bits?

Comment: There are Murmurhash64 and 64B. See e.g. http://code.google.com/p/maatkit/issues/attachmentText?id=19&aid=7029841249934490324&name=MurmurHash64.cpp.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Aha sorry I should have done more research :P  Yeah both Nemo's and Gene's suggestions will work for me.

Comment: there's nothing particularly *consistent* about murmurhash itself.  it can be used in a consistent hashing scheme, but so can any other uniform hash function.  your question seems to be "What are some 64 bit (non-cryptographic) hash functions?"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Nemo and Gene, I could have just used Murmurhash64 or used Murmurhash to produce a 128-bit value and discard 64 bits.